# Allocating memory with 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc, 2d

I'm trying to use dynamic memory allocation with a 2D array and I can't seem to get my function to work as intended. I want to pass my function a long string of characters, break up and store certain parts as individual strings (in their own character arrays), then add them to a 2D array and return the final thing. The part of the function that splits the string up and stores what I want works fine. The memory allocation is what I'm doing wrong.

For example, I pass my function the string  "0,,10000,10000,"Albany Hwy After Armadale Rd","",-32.1479054960,116.0201957650,4" and it pulls out '10000', '-32.1479054960' and '116.0201957650', stores them in their own arrays, then adds it all into one array called 'stop'. What I'm (attempting) to do is allocate memory for my 3 strings that I will store, then as I add the strings I allocate memory for them as they are added.

Here is my function:

```
 char **getStopData(char line[]) {
int commas = 0;
int len = strlen(line);
char **stop = malloc(3); //Block of memory for each string
char stop_id[20]; //Temp array to build stop_id string 
char lat[20]; //Temp array to build lat string
char lon[20]; //Temp array to build lon string
int counter;

for(int i = 0; i <len; i++) { 
    if(line[i] == ',')  {
        commas++;
        counter = 0;
        continue;
    }
    switch(commas) { //Build strings here and store them - works fine
        case 2 :
            stop_id[counter++] = line[i]; 
            if(line[i+1] == ',') stop_id[counter] = '\0';
            break;
        case 6 : 
            lat[counter++] =  line[i]; 
            if(line[i+1] == ',') lat[counter] = '\0';
            break;
        case 7 : 
            lon[counter++] =  line[i];
            if(line[i+1] == ',') lon[counter] = '\0';
            break;
    }
}
//Assign memory for each string to be added to 'stop' & add my strings to 'stop'
stop[0] = malloc(sizeof(stop_id));
stop[0] = stop_id;
stop[1] = malloc(sizeof(lat));
stop[1] = lat;
stop[2] = malloc(sizeof(lon));
stop[2] = lon;

return stop;
}
```

And my main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char  **niceRows = getStopData(argv[1]);
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(niceRows); i++) {    
    printf("%d\n",*niceRows[i]);
    free(niceRows[i]);
}
free(niceRows);
return 0;
}
```

When I run my function I get a bunch of runtime errors to do with my memory allocation. `error for object 0x7fff5266bb70: pointer being freed was not allocated  set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Comment: I'm not sure I see the interest of a 2D array here, if all the sub-arrays are supposed to be 1-float long (while somehow taking their byte size from a character array)

Comment: Sorry it might seem confusing. I'm planning to have multiple versions of this function for other strings that won't be broken up into just floats. I will rewrite it for characters instead of floats (meaning I will still need a 2D array).

Comment: `stop = malloc(3)` should be `stop = malloc(3 * sizeof(*stop))`.

Comment: `stop[0] = stop_id;` You need to go back and read up about the basics of the C language before moving on to 2D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

this line returns a pointer to allocated memory

```
stop[ 0 ] = malloc( sizeof( stop_id ) );
```

the next line **overrides** it and changes the pointer to point at stop_id

```
stop[0] = stop_id;
```

same for stop[ 1 ] and stop [ 2 ]

what you want to do it

```
memcpy( stop[ 0 ], stop_id, 20 );
```

**EDIT** ( via M Oehm ): 
you should also change

```
char **stop = malloc(3);
```

to

```
char **stop = malloc( 3 * sizeof( char * ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are major problems in your code.

```
float **stop = malloc(3); //Block of memory for each string
```

only allocates 3 bytes or memory which is **not** enough. You should write:

```
float **stop = malloc(3 * sizeof(float *)); //Block of memory for each string
```

Because this will allocate memory for 3 `float *`.

Later, you have `stop[0] = malloc(sizeof(stop_id));` you alloc 20 bytes of memory, but you will only write a **`float`** in it. You should better write:

```
stop[0] = malloc(sizeof(float));
```

Same for `stop[1]` and `stop[2]`.

And finally you have `for (int i=0; i<sizeof(niceRows); i++) {`

`niceRows` is a `float **`, ie an *address*. Its size will be 4 on a 32 bit system and 8 on a 64 bits one, but definitely not what you want.

It should be `for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {`

But you do not need a `float **` here: a `float *` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your allocation should be:

```
float **stop = malloc(3 * sizeof *stop);
```

`malloc` takes the number of bytes, which you can get with `sizeof`. This is C's way to cater for arbitrary types in low-level functions like `memcpy`, `memset`, `fwrite`, `qsort` and ´malloc`: You operate on byte memory with ´void *` pointers. This loses the type information, but allows you to use any type by specifying the type's size in bytes with `sizeof(T)`.

(This is also prone to errors, because you have to keep the data and type in sync.)

In main, you try to get the length of the allocated pointer-to-float array with `sizeof`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(niceRows); i++) ...
```

That doesn't work. The size of `niceRows` is the size of a pointer, which is either 4 or 8, depending on your system.

There is no way of knowing how much memory was allocated to a pointer. You must keep this information as a separate value. The best you can do is to bundle both pointer to allocated memory and the size information in a struct.

In your case, `getStopData` always returns an array of three pointers to float. You don't need length information here, but you should probably document the fact that the returned array has always three entries. So:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) ...
```

A better design than an array might be a structure, where the names of the entries already tell you what data you are looking at.

Finally, you should probably initialise the temporary char buffers `stop_id`, `lat` and ´lon` to catch the cases where there are fewer than 7 commas.

Answer (score -1):

- Using pointer-to-pointer to get a 2D array is nonsense, it is widely spread but incorrect, bad practice. A pointer to a dynamic 2D arrays is obtained by

  ```
  char (*ptr)[x][y] = malloc(char[x][y]);
  ```

  or in case your compiler was designed by dinosaurs:

  ```
  char* ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * x * y);
  ```

  Everything else will not give you a proper 2D array allocated in adjacent memory.
- In your particular case, you probably don't even want a 2D array, you want an array of pointers, each pointer pointing to a string of variable length. Such an array is declared as `char* stop[3];`.
- In C, you cannot copy arrays with the `=` assignment operator. You have to use memcpy or strcpy.
- You can only use the `sizeof` operator on arrays that were allocated statically.